# Regex to extract values between brackets

Tags: regex, bash

I've looked at a few threads on this and just can't seem to get it working. Clearly an issue with my regex statement and/or bash_rematch.

There will only ever be a max of 4 x ()'s

Have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
brackets_regex="\((.*?)\)"
text="random date (entry1) some more random data (entry2) random (entry3) random data (entry4)"

if  [[ $text =~ $brackets_regex ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]};
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]};
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[3]};
fi
```

Expected output should be:

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
entry4
```

Current output:

```
(entry1) some more random data (entry2) random (entry3) random data (entry4)
entry1) some more random data (entry2) random (entry3) random data (entry4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gnu grep:

```
grep -oP '\(\K[^)]*' <<< "$text"
entry1
entry2
entry3
entry4
```

Using gnu-awk:

```
text="random date (entry1) some more random data (entry2) random (entry3) random data (entry4)"
awk -v FPAT='\\([^)]*\\)' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/[()]/, "", $i); print $i}}' <<< "$text"
entry1
entry2
entry3
entry4
```

Comment: How easy would it be to assign those values to variables. So Var1=entry1, Var2=entry2 etc

Comment: It can be assigned to an array: `arr=($(grep -oP '\(\K[^)]*' <<< "$text"))`

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**:

- To extract text between round brackets (=parentheses): `brackets_regex='\(([^()]*)\)'`
- To extract text between square brackets: `brackets_regex='\[([^][]*)]'`

Bash regex does not support lazy quantifiers. You need to rely on a negated character class `[^()]` matching any character but `(` and `)`.

Here is another way of achieving what you need:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
text="random date (entry1) some more random data (entry2) random (entry3) random data (entry4)"
brackets_regex="\(([^()]*)\)"
for s in ${text[@]}; do
    if [[ ${s} =~ $brackets_regex ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
    fi
done
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/YjvVfL)

Output:

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
entry4
```